# Android. Set default text of an alert dialog box based on another text

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Good afternoon,

I would like to open an input dialog box and set the default EditText value of the 'editTextDialogUserInput', based on the value of the TextView 'labUrl'. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Many thanks for your help.

Best wishes,
Laurent

```
package laurent.ch.domoos;

/**
 * Created by Laurent on 27.02.2016.
 */

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button btnStartDomoos;
private Button btnChangeUrl;
private TextView labUrl;
private EditText result;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    showToast();

    btnStartDomoos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);
    btnChangeUrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeUrl);
    labUrl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labUrl) ;
    result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

    btnStartDomoos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", labUrl.getText().toString());

            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    btnChangeUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get prompts.xml view
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

            // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    // get user input and set it to result
                                    // edit text
                                    labUrl.setText(userInput.getText());

                                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(userInput.getWindowToken(), 0);
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(userInput.getWindowToken(), 0);

                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}

private void showToast(){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Bienvenue dans Domoos ";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [android popup library](https://github.com/00ec454/pop) and try the following code. it cuts lots of cuttler

```
package laurent.ch.domoos;

/**
 * Created by Laurent on 27.02.2016.
 */

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private Button btnStartDomoos;
 private Button btnChangeUrl;
 private TextView labUrl;
 private EditText result;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  final Context context = this;

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  showToast();

  btnStartDomoos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);
  btnChangeUrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeUrl);
  labUrl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labUrl);
  result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

  btnStartDomoos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("url", labUrl.getText().toString());

    startActivity(intent);
   }

  });

  btnChangeUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    Pop.on(MainActivity.this).with().layout(R.layout.prompts)
     .when(new Pop.Yah() {
      @Override
      public void clicked(DialogInterface dialog, View view) {
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(userInput.getWindowToken(), 0);
       dialog.dismiss();
      }
     })
     .when(new Pop.Nah() {
      @Override
      public void clicked(DialogInterface dialog, View view) {
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(userInput.getWindowToken(), 0);
       dialog.dismiss();
      }
     }).show(new Pop.View() {
      @Override
      public void prepare(View view) {
       EditText userInput = (EditText) view
        .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
       userInput.setText(labUrl.getText());
      }
     });

   }
  });
 }

 private void showToast() {
  Context context = getApplicationContext();
  CharSequence text = "Bienvenue dans Domoos ";
  int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
  toast.show();
 }
}
```